# Django model file example is a bit weird to me

Tags: django

[In the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/) I understand the principle of this example, but I dont get how it works technically (see my comments in the code):

```
>>> import os
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> initial_path = car.photo.path
>>> car.photo.name = 'cars/chevy_ii.jpg'
>>> new_path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + car.photo.name
>>> # Move the file on the filesystem: it's using strings: initial_path and new_path:
>>> os.rename(initial_path, new_path)
>>> # the following "save()" seems to "guess" that it has been renamed... but how??
>>> car.save()
>>> car.photo.path
'/media/cars/chevy_ii.jpg'
>>> car.photo.path == new_path
True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ImageField`'s `path` is a property constructing the path of the field's storage path (`MEDIA_ROOT` in this case) and the object's `name`.

So by changing `car.photo.name` the in-memory object's `path` is already the same as `new_path`. No guesses or magic needed.

My guess is that the example is trying to be more explicit by assagning and using `new_path`.

Comment: I see but why does `os.rename(initial_path, new_path)` have an *effect* on `car.photo.path`? `initial_path` and `new_path` are strings, not objects (unless I'm wrong?)!

Comment: It does not have effect on `car.photo.path`. It simply moves the file on `initial_path` to `new_path`. It has effect on the file system. All changes to `car.photo` are explicit and we have already told it what it's new path is going to be.

Comment: If you look inside [`fields.files.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L55) and [`storage.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/core/files/storage.py#L323), you can see that the property `path` is constructed based on `field.name`. The lines `car.photo.name = 'cars/chevy_ii.jpg'` and `car.save()` update the path (which would give you a 404). The `os.rename` simply moves the image to the new path.

Comment: @PatrykBratkowski, not the field name but the `FieldFile` name, which is the name of the file for the field. The field name in this case is `photo` and it does not appear in the `path`

Comment: Correct. I was using the term `field` in a generic sense which may admittedly be confusing. The `field` in this case is `car.photo`, and Django returns a `FieldFile` instance as a proxy. Anyway, I hope it helps clear up Olivier's confusion.